# solution of a linear equation and norm 1

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, vectors

I'm trying to do kmean clustering using the *cosinus pseudo distance* $d(A, B) =   (1 - \frac{A \cdot B}{\|A\|\cdot\|B\|})$

At the seconde step of each iteration, I have a set of points belonging to a  cluster and I want to find the *centroid* according to the *cosinus pseudo distance*.

So given a set of vectors $X_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$  for $n$ in $[0..N]$, I'm trying to find the vector A that solves:

$$\min_{A \in \mathbb{R}^m} 1 - \sum_{n=0}^N ( \frac{A \cdot X_n}{\|A\| \cdot \|X_n\|}$$

which is resolving

$$\max_{A \in \mathbb{R}^m} 1 - \sum_{n=0}^N ( \frac{A \cdot X_n}{\|A\| \cdot \|X_n\|}$$

The cosinus pseudo distance is indifferent on the norm of the vectors, so I choose $\|A\| = 1$

$ = \max_{A \in \mathbb{R}^m} \sum_{n=0}^N ( \frac{A \cdot X_n}{\|X_n\|} )$, with $\|A\| = 1$

$= \max_{A \in \mathbb{R}^m} \sum_{n=0}^N \sum_{i=0}^m ( \frac{A_i \cdot {X_n}_i}{\|X_n\|} )$, with $\|A\| = 1$

$= \max_{A \in \mathbb{R}^m} \sum_{i=0}^m \sum_{n=0}^N  ( \frac{A_i \cdot {X_n}_i}{\|X_n\|} )$, with $\|A\| = 1$

$=\max_{A \in \mathbb{R}^m} \sum_{i=0}^m A_i \cdot ( \sum_{n=0}^N  \frac{{X_n}_i}{\|X_n\|} )$, with $\|A\| = 1$

$= \max_{A \in \mathbb{R}^m} \sum_{i=0}^m Y_i \cdot A_i $, with $\|A\| = 1$ and $ Y_i = ( \sum_{n=0}^N  \frac{{X_n}_i}{\|X_n\|} )$

So finally I have to find the minimum of a linear equation under the constraint of normality of the solution vector.

How do I solve this ? Is it a known problem ?

Comment: I realize the last formula is equivalent to a scalar product $Y \cdot A$  which for Y and A of constant Norm is maximazed for Y and A having same direction.

So I just have to take Y and normalize to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that the last equation is a dot product of vectors $Y$ and $A$ so as Y and A have a fixed norm, it only depends on the angle of the two vectors and is maximum when A is in the same direction as Y, that is A is Y normalized to 1.

$A = \frac{Y} {\|Y\|}$ with $Y_i = sum_{n=0}^N \frac{{X_n}_i}{\|X_n\|}$